# Lisp- "[Function name] Is not a Number"

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

So I have this simple expression to evaluate and list the two roots of a quadratic equation:

```
(defun QUADRATIC (A B C) (list (/  (+  (- B) (sqrt(- (* B B) - (* 4 A C)))) (* 2 A)) (/  (- (- B) (sqrt(- (* B B) - (* 4 A C)))) (* 2 A))))
```

But when I evaluate it in CLISP with any three numbers for parameters, say

```
(quadratic 2 2 2)
```

I get the following error: `(quadratic 2 2 2) is not a number`

I am sure there is an easy fix but I can't figure it out!

Comment: unformatted code on one line looks unreadable in most programming languages, incl. Lisp. That would be the first you would need to improve on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntactic error in your definition (and using an editor that format properly the code help in finding this kind of errors).

The correct definition is:

```
 (defun quadratic (A B C) 
    (list (/  (+ (- B) (sqrt(- (* B B) (* 4 A C)))) 
              (* 2 A)) 
          (/  (- (- B) (sqrt(- (* B B) (* 4 A C)))) 
              (* 2 A))))
```

while you have an extra `-` in the `sqrt` call: `(sqrt(- (* B B) - (* 4 A C)))) (* 2 A))` (the second `-`).

The reason for the particular error message is that `-` used not in function position is a special variable that refer to the current form (see the [specification](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v__.htm)).

Comment: Thank you! that fixed it. I am still not used to this prefix notation of LISP. I expected there was a more clever problem here, I do not know if a syntactic error is worth a question here. I am using Notepad++ for lack of a better editor, is there are better.

Comment: Visual Studio Code also has a number of Lisp extensions.